# In WPF Itemscontrol is not showing result properly, it is mergin all records at one place

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I am decorating my ItemsControl basis on the records, but it is overlapping all records on each other, i have created a screenshot of the output, and i am pasting the xaml part for the same.

```
<Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2"  Grid.Row="1" >
        <ItemsControl x:Name="productsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{DynamicResource DataLabel}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Click="btnEdit_Click" Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource EditButtonStyle}" Content="Edit" />
                                <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Click="btnDelete_Click" Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" Content="Delete" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding MyRow}" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding MyColumn}" />
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
```

[image]

Comment: even though you bind `Grid.Row`/`Grid.Column`, Grid in ItemsPanelTemplate has only one row/column. so Grid.Row/Grid.Column bindings don't make any difference. you need multiple RowDefinition / ColumnDefinition s

Comment: Yes ASh, I have removed them just after i seen it.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the issue by removing following code form ItemsPanelTemplate. And I used WrapPanel instead Grid.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Above code replaced with following...

```
 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" />
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```